# Getting Started With Angular Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just getting started with Angular and seem to have fallen down at the first hurdle. I wanted to build a simple skeleton app to start with. I pretty much copied the code of the angularjs.org site and am getting an error talking about injection... Sorry to code dump, but I have no clue where the bug is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="triangular">
<head>

    <title>Angular Skeleton</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" /> 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-route-segment/1.3.0/angular-route-segment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

         var a = angular;

         var t = a.module('triangular', ['ngRoute']);

         t.config(['$routeProvider',
         function($routeProvider) {
             $routeProvider.
             when('/page1', {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/test/partials/partial1.html',
                controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
             }).
             when('/page2', {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/test/partials/partial2.html',
                controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
             }).
             otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/page1'
             });
         }]);

         t.controller('Page1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)
         {
             $scope.placeholder = 'Test';
         }]);

         t.controller('Page2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)
         {
             $scope.placeholder = 'Test2';
         }]);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view=""></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error: Error: [$injector:modulerr].
The link it's providing isn't that useful. It told me to include the route segment js file, which I did, but the error persisted.

Comment: What's the link it's providing? May not be useful to you, but it could be to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to your head right below where you include angular. I had a similar issue and this fixed it right away.

Comment: Thanks man, I guess I was just including the wrong version of the file, how annoying!

Comment: Happy to help! This issue can be pretty annoying indeed. Usually if you get an error about $injector, it has something to do with not including a module file. In my experience you can always use the exact same URL as you do for your angular.js file for your modules, just change the "angular" part to "angular-[modulename]" (not 100% sure this is always true, but it has always worked for me).